# SUM which adds together figures collected on the same date

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

For example all data collected on 1/1/22 would all added together and outputed as one result and data collected on 2/1/22 would all added together be another result. I will add my query bellow to help with any question.

```
SELECT SUM(duration)
FROM sessions
WHERE (app_id = '' OR app_id ='' OR app_id ='' OR app_id =''OR app_id ='***')
AND date(created ) between '2022-03-19' and '2022-03-26' 
and hour(created ) between '16' and '18';
AND (media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='' OR media_src='****');
```

The current query takes all data collected during a week during 16:00 and 18:00 and outputs the total across the whole week however I want the data to be added together and divided based on date outputing total figures for each day in the date range.

Comment: Please read [this suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977) and update the question. As far as I understood you only need a *group by date(created)*

Comment: Thank you for the help this has helped resolve my issue